# Add drop down list / combo box into excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, cells

How would I add a drop down list (or combo box) into a cell on Excel 2010?

Comment: Yes, or drop down list, ver 2010.

Comment: I edited your question. I suggest you try a [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&btnI=I%27m%20Feeling%20Lucky&q=excel+add+combo+box#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=excel+add+drop+down+list+2010&oq=excel+add+dro&gs_l=serp.3.2.0l4.2457.2836.0.4697.3.3.0.0.0.1.676.936.0j2j5-1.3.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.K5HZORigNkk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=a1937293c9c50b24&biw=1280&bih=903). This link currently has video and official Microsoft guides

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually the simplest way to achieve that is to:

- **prepare the list** next to your table or on other spreadsheet (just input all available values in a column) - it'll be a source for your list of values and it may be hidden later, if you want
- **mark a cell** (or a range of cells) in which list should be displayed
- select Data > Data Validation > **Data Validation**
- select **Allow: List**
- indicate the list prepared before as a **Source**
- **confirm**

The drop-down list is ready. For combo-box you should use VBA, I believe. But you may also use the method described above and e.g. prepare just two-elements list containing "**Yes/No**" or "**True/False**", which is generally the same.

The method should work regardless of Excel's version.

Answer (score 4):

Found this answer when looking to do the same thing myself, while experimenting discovered, there's a second option which means you don't need to use a defined cell range. Entries can be added directly to Source.

1. Select all the cells you want to have a drop down box
2. Click > Data Validation
3. Allow > List
4. In Source enter any values you want separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
This example will create a vertical range of 10 cells in which each cell can be filled from values selected from a drop down list which will appear in each cell.

Setup:
Select or insert a blank sheet into a workbook.
Add the following letters to the associated cell locations.
A in cell C1
B in cell C2
C in cell C3
D in cell C4
Select the cells A1 to A10
Within the Ribbon Bar, select 'Data, Data Validation, Data Validation'
    Within the resulting dialog box, select the Settings tab.
    Within the Settings tab select the following 'Validation criteria:'
        Allow: List
        Uncheck Ignore blank 
        Enter C1:C4 for the Source:
    Select OK
With your mouse select a cell in the range of cells A1:A10.
A drop down arrow will appear next to any of the cells in the range A1:A10.
The dropdown arrow will not appear in any other cell in the sheet.

Demonstrate:
Demonstrate the results by selecting various entries in the cells within the range A1:A10.